# Angular - Styles not being applied to my custom components from parent

Tags: angular

I don't understand why my margin isn't being applied in this example. Seems strait forward enough.

App Template:

```
<my-component class="my-class">Test</my-component>
<div>Some Conent</div>
```

App Styles:

```
.my-class { margin-bottom: 30px;  } 
div { background-color: red; }
```

Component Template:

```
<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

The div gets  red background, but there is no margin between the two;

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oUczApNhhPrAOKy5Iclp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the component selectors from angular aren't "real" html elements, therefore they have no default styling. Because of that the browser doesn't know how to display them and doesn't apply any styles which have an impact on the css layout around the component (e.g. `margin` or `height`).

To fix this you need to apply the css `display` property  with any value except `none` to your component.

For example:

```
.my-class {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the well explained reason!

Comment: A brilliant tip!